# File manager API in PHP

Tags: php, ftp

I have a plan to develop an online file manager application to manage(add/edit/update/copy/delete) my client's(My business clients) server files. Instead of using Filezila or any such FTP applications. Because there is no such options to track the file changes history in those applications.

My idea is

1. Placing an agent file in production server (http://example-client-site.com/file-manager-api.php)
2. Call the agent file (file-manager-api.php) from my project management system, which is hosted online. (http://example-proj-mgmt.com)
3. So i can access the production server files from my project management system like REST API , without connecting through FTP.

My question is, what are the security issues in the way of access the server through URL REST API method ?

Please give me some idea to overcome the security issues.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: "Placing an agent file in client server", what do you mean? In "client server" ?!

Comment: Sorry I made little confuse "client server" , here client mean "My clients whom i'm working for"

Comment: There is something similar, the PHP File Manager http://phpfm.sourceforge.net

Comment: Yes, phpfm.sourceforge.net is very simple and lightweight file manager, but if i use it, then i have to install it in all my production servers, my aim is to access the server files without toughing production server. thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Concept is good, I only have concerned with security. What you can do is you can keep something like Token or Authorization key or such, where only authorized users can access it, as the concerned is REST API.

1. Authorization (Tokn key)
2. Protect Against Cross-site Request Forgery
3. Insecure Direct Object References
4. URL Validations
5. Secure Parsing & Strong Typing
6. Validate Incoming Content-types
7. JSON Encoding
8. Message Integrity

Comment: Thank for your suggestions

#1. Some security tokens can be used
#2. Only allowed IP's can accept the request at destination server
#3, #4, The agent file will be unique, will be used like md5('some key').'.php';
4. The agent file will accept the request from a specified static IP only.

I just want to know, if there is any possibilities to break the system using "Man in middle attack", "ip spoofing" or such things.